# inputmask for documentum

Tags: documentum

I know that I can validate an input field by adding a inputmaskvalidator tag. I read the documentum doc :

> The mask character string:
>
> - ## : numeric characters
> - & : all characters
> - A : alphanumeric characters only
> - ? : alphabetic characters only
> - U : uppercase alphabetic characters only
> - L : lowercase alphabetic characters only
>
> Example: date mask ##/##/## permits
>   the input date 12/24/95 To use one of
>   the mask characters as a literal
>   member of the mask string, place a
>   double slash (\) preceding the
>   character.

Let's guess I want to accept **double only** to store it as a double in the content server. What must be the inputmask value?

Something like that?

```
<dmf:inputmaskvalidator inputmask="#.#" controltovalidate="my_double" name="my_double_validator"/>
```

or

```
<dmf:inputmaskvalidator inputmask="##.##" controltovalidate="my_double" name="my_double_validator"/>
```

Comment: Since I did not get any answer from the SO community, I will write my pseudo answer : I used a Regular Expression in the component java class.  
Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use other type of validator. Inputmaskvalidator is bad for your purpose. Use for example regexpvalidator. Example you can find on [this page](http://www.bluefishgroup.com/library/2004/validation-in-wdk/):